# Why is the absolute overlay not working on these elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-website

Im trying to do a simple semi-transparent overlay over my webinterface that should display if the client is not connected to the WLAN network of the server.

The problem is, some elements just don't seem to react to the overlay, means, they don't change their original opacity / color, including regular headings, checkboxes, png's, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zfsT.png)sliders, buttons and progressbars. Regular span elements and other divs get the desired effect. I tried to experiment with z-index, it doesn't do anything.

The CSS of the overlay is as follows:

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: Rubik;
  color: rgb(60, 60, 60);
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.no-connection-blind {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #000000;
}
```

It is positioned on top of the body:

```
 <body onload="initFunctions()">
    <div class="no-connection-blind" id="no-connection-blind" />
```

I tried changing z-indexes to low values for the non reacting elements and high indexes for the overlay, without any effect. Any ideas what to check?

Comment: Please create a reproducable example on https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't properly close the `<div>` element. I would suggest using

```
<div class="no-connection-blind" id="no-connection-blind"></div>
```

I reproduced your issue and fix it this way. Here's the solution that worked for me.

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: Rubik;
  color: rgb(60, 60, 60);
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.no-connection-blind {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="no-connection-blind" id="no-connection-blind"></div>
<h1>Title</h1>
<label><input type="checkbox" /> I'm a checkbox</label>
<p>This is just a text</p>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
```

Comment: Damn, it was really just this, didn't expect that. Thank you!